# recursive change sed grep and sed

Tags: recursion, sed, grep

I'm still working in this little script but still having problems. Getting error

```
sed: no input files
```

I think the problem is on:

```
for i in `cat sed_output.txt` do sed 's/$oldstr/$newstr/g' > sed_output_new_old_string.txt done
```

```
echo "Enter string to be replaced"
read OLDSTRING
echo "Enter string to be placed"
read NEWSTRING
oldstr=$OLDSTRING #string to be replaced
newstr=$NEWSTRING #new string to be placed
echo "Enter folder path where we will find the string"
read FOLDERPATH

### grep oldstring and output it in grep_output.txt
grep -rl $oldstr $FOLDERPATH > grep_output.txt

###  spaces or special characters on filenames, use sed to enclose them with quote 
for i in `cat grep_output.txt`
do sed -e "s/'/'\\\\''/g;s/\(.*\)/'\1'/" grep_output.txt  > sed_output.txt
done

for i in `cat sed_output.txt`
do sed 's/$oldstr/$newstr/g' > sed_output_new_old_string.txt
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

- You know the file on which you need to do the substitution
- You know what needs to be substituted
- You know the replacement

then;

```
sed 's/substitution/replacement/g' filename
```

will scan file line by line looking for substitution text and replace it with replacement text.

For recursive substitution, you can do;

```
for file in path/to/folder; do
    sed -i.bak 's/substitute/replacement/g' "$file"
done
```

The `-i` option will do in file changes. I added `.bak` to it so you have the backup of original files which will be renamed to `file.bak`.

If you are using variables in your `sed` then I would suggest you to use `"` instead of `'` so that you variables gets interpolated correctly.

Comment: I did the for i in `cat grep_output.txt`
do sed -i "s/$oldstr/$newstr/g" $i > sed_output_new_old_string.txt
done

Comment: You don't need to do `cat`. `sed` by default parses file line by line. You can simply do `sed "s/$oldstr/$newstr/g" grep_output.txt > new file`. You don't need `-i` option if you are re-directing the output to new file. It is only for in-file changes.